# Populate a input with a date based on selected option (date today + days)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to do this using jQuery

i have a select like

```
<select id="Plan_Id" name="Plan_Id">
    <option value="30">Month</option>
    <option value="365">Annual</option>
</select>
```

then i have a input

```
<input name="date" id="date_picker" type="text" class="text date_picker" />
```

so based on the option i select i want to get the date today + value and show on the input was

m-d-Y.

so if today is january 07 and i select 30 -> month

my input will be populated with 02-06-2012

Comment: What have you got so far? It's always easier to provide advice if there is some existing code to add to...

Comment: This place is to learn and not to place your requirement and get the solution for it. First show us what you have tried and we will help sorting your mistakes.

Comment: Actually i did this manually i click on the input show me the calendary i select the date i want - record in my database well.. also but i dont know in jquery how to get the value of the select and sum with date(today) and update the input. ive looking on google over a hour and dont find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than general googling, you want to look specifically at a [JavaScript reference about the Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and at the [jQuery UI datepicker reference](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/). Between the two you'll have all the information you'll need to work this out. But since I already happen to know the answer (or an answer)...

Given a JavaScript date object:

```
var today = new Date();  // current date returned by constructor with no params
```

You can add *n* days to it by setting the day-of-the-month to the current value plus *n* - the month and/or year will be automatically adjusted as appropriate. So:

```
today.setDate(today.getDate() + 30);
today.setDate(today.getDate() + 365);
```

Put together with the jQuery datepicker "setDate" method:

```
var theDate = new Date();

theDate.setDate(theDate.getDate() + 365);

$("#date_picker").datepicker("setDate", theDate);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WUdWs/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here is my way  http://jsfiddle.net/gurkavcu/bRXmK/

```
$(function() {
   $("#date_picker").datepicker({

   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 

       // Create selectedDay  
       var selectedDay = new Date(inst.currentYear,inst.currentMonth,inst.currentDay);
       // Add day amount according to select box
       selectedDay.setDate(selectedDay.getDate()+parseInt($("#Plan_Id").val(),10));
       // Show new day with your own style
       $(this).val((selectedDay.getMonth()+1)+"-"+
                    selectedDay.getDate()+"-"+
                    selectedDay.getFullYear());       
       }   
   });
});
```